Is it a good idea to lie about your current or last salary to get a low paying job?
I was laid off from my last job due to restructuring. My salary at my last job was about 1.4 mn Rupees / yr. I have been on lookout for new job since last 6 months but I am not successful so far due to various reasons. I am struggling financially and as a result I am bit desperate for a job. Therefore, I am applying for low paying jobs i.e. in the range of 0.7 - 1.1 mn rs/yr. But I am doubtful whether any recruiter will consider my profile seriously for the job for long term perspective if they know my last salary. Hence I was considering if to lie about my last salary to make it less than actual would be helpful.
I understand I would have to provide my last salary slip to new company and eventually they will get to know about my last salary which might lead to a bigger problem. But I am not sure what to do get a low paying job.

Please do not vandalize your post. By posting on any Stack Exchange site, you've granted them the rights to the content under the CC BY-SA 4.0 licence, regardless of any changes you may make. Vandalizing your post(s) can result in the edit being reverted, and continuous vandalism may lead to your account being temporarily suspended.

Telling a lie that will certainly be found out eventually in order to get the job is a bad idea. Personally, if I had a candidate do that, I would wonder what else they lied about in the interview process. I would certainly have a very hard time trusting them going forward.

I.... do not see why you'd want to but
There's no reason to lie about it. Just tell them your expected salary and be done with it, I've never seen anyone get into trouble for going for lower paying jobs

Not true. The trouble here is that you don't get hired in the first place since the employer assumes you are only accepting because of short term financial stress. Even if hired, you'll keep looking and as soon as you find something better you are out.  Hiring people costs time and money and employers strongly prefer hires which feel "long term viable"

That honestly requires you to make it sound like that's what you're doing. You were fired, you need to make a living, so you apply for a job. As long as you don't go out of their way to tell them "I'm desperate and need the money" you can just say "well I was let go" especially if the reason wasn't your inadequacy

No, we don't recommend to commit fraud. Especially one guaranteed to be found out.

It might be lying, but I don't see how this can be fraud.

Lying to get monetary gains is literally the dictionary definition of fraud https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fraud

I think you'd be hardpressed to be convicted of fraud in a case like this.

@MarkRotteveel You asked how this can be fraud, that is what the word means. I am not fluent in indian law enough to opine on prosecution possibility, feel free to provide an answer and explain.

@MarkRotteveel The (supposed) low likelihood of being prosecuted and convicted doesn't mean that it isn't fraud. By that logic, fraud is ok as long as you can get away with it without legal consequences.
